# Analytical Reasoning Question III

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics

I tried to solve the number problem below and would like to get input on the final solution I came up with. Thanks in advance!

*(a) If n is a multiple of 7, how many numbers there that are multiples of 7 between
n and n + 700 (inclusively)?
Answer 
** 101*

Comment: That's correct but you should really ask for input on your *reasoning* rather than just your answer.

Comment: I Will do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every 7th number is a multiple of 7. So, the multiples *bigger* than $n$ are $n+7$, $n+2\cdot7$, and so on. Dividing 700 by 7 tells us that there are 100 such numbers, and we also need to count $n$ itself, giving 101.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure if what I had was correct.